# OpenCV Aruco Make Failure

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, markers, aruco

I have attempted to install the Aruco Markers module for OpenCV but having issues when applying make.

I have been following this tutorial: uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26

Image of make error.

[image: image of make error]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that this is caused by a version mismatch between the main OpenCV library and the opencv_contrib extension (Aruco is part of it). Check this page for correct matching contrib library to your OpenCV Release: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases